# How to show in search results posts with a particular tag in a particular category?

Tags: categories, functions, wp-query, customization, url-rewriting

As the home page of my blog I've a static page.
There I want to show the navigation of the site.

Category1

- Sub-Category1

  - tag1, tag2, tag3

Category1

- Sub-Category2

  - tag1, tag2, tag3

Category2

- Sub-Category1

  - tag1, tag2, tag3

Category2

- Sub-Category2

  - tag1, tag2, tag3

All the above words are hyperlinks.

Now what I need is, when a user clicks on tag1 under subcategory1 in category2, all the posts of category2, in subcategory1 having tag1 shall be returned.

is it possible to have a URL like domain.com/category2/subcategory1/tag1 for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Given the way categories & tags are setup in WordPress this would not work from a logical standpoint. The issue here is that tags have no way to be connected directly to a category, they are mutually exclusive from each other. The subcategories would work because a subcategory is directly related to is parent category but tags are non hierarchical and have no parent/child relationship capabilities on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

@GrSrv
It is not possible in vanilla WordPress as the tags, and categories are separate entities.

Categories would offer you a hierarchical parent/child relationship, and could accomplish this.

- CategoryParent1

  - CategoryChild1

    - CategoryGrandchild1, CategoryGrandchild2, CategoryGrandchild3
- CategoryParent1

  - CategoryChild2

    - CategoryGrandchild1, CategoryGrandchild2, CategoryGrandchild3
- CategoryParent2

  - CategoryChild1

    - CategoryGrandchild1, CategoryGrandchild2, CategoryGrandchild3
- CategoryParent2

  - CategoryChild2

    - CategoryGrandchild1, CategoryGrandchild2, CategoryGrandchild3

Alternately, if you wish to retain the tags as you have them, you could use WordPress SEO to rewrite the tag URLs, and essentially 'spoof' the URL.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

I hope that helps!